# PHP form/prepared statements bug

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am creating a user registration form and I'm having an issue with the prepared statements. If I add an `exit();` in the code, the sign up won't lead to anywhere. If I don't add the `exit();`, the form will display the correct error messages but then dismiss them the second try around.

Also, another (noob) question, how do I implement an error message for an already registered email as well? I added `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=? AND user_email=?";` and `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $name, $email);` but I couldn't get the error message to display.

So far for the prepared statements issue:

```
else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?sqlerror");
            exit();
        }

        else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $name);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        array_push($error_array, "Oops! This username is already taken.<br>");
        exit();
        }
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: You want name *or* email matches, not both.

Answer (score 2):

you do not need the exit because you already have the header
for question registered email:
 You can use a function num_rows,  http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root", "", "tables");
 $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=? AND 
  user_email=?");
 $query->execute();
 $query->store_result();

 $rows = $query->num_rows;
```

and make an if

```
if($rows>0){
 //message error
}
```

Comment: Should be `OR` to cover two different uniqueness matches. Plus if all you care about is hit or no hit, `SELECT id` or `SELECT COUNT(*)` to avoid loading potentially large amounts of data.